# What's the graphical solution or the analytical solution to $|z^2-1|\geq 8$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conic-sections, complex-geometry

The problem also states that the answer should be a circle of radius $3$ centered in $(0,0), Z=3e^{i\theta}.$

I've arrived to $$(x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)\geq 63\,$$ and I've graphed this in wolfram alpha but the solution which it plots is an ellipse, at least from what I tell, and well that weird equation I've arrived to doesn't really look like is going to be a circle.

I'm stucked with that equation above and I don't really know how to end up showing that it has the equation of an ellipse or whatever shape it might be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean all points outside the circle is the answer? There is a greater than or equal to sign in the question

Comment: Obviously $z$ is a solution whenever $|z|\ge3$. But those aren't all the solutions. Consider points like $z=2.99e^{\pi i/4}$ with squares close to but a bit below $9i$. In other words, whoever claimed that *all* the solutions satisfy $|z|\ge3$ is wrong.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Yes all points outside the circle or ellipse is the answer

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yeah that's what I believe too, the circle is not the answer. And well I don't really know how you get the answer of $|z| \geq 3$ but what concerns me is how to get the right answer which might be an ellipse.

Comment: It looks like an ellipse with major axis 3 along x and minor axis of $\sqrt 7$ along y axis if I'm not wrong

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan yeah that might be it and well I know I said "graphical solution" but what I meant was that I wanted to find the equation analytically. That´s where I'm stucked. Thank all of you for your replies at the moment

Comment: The boundary is a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval). After all,
$$|z^2-1|=|z-1|\cdot |z+1|$$ is the product of distances from $z$ to the points $1$ and $-1$. On an appropriate Cassini oval this is constant.

Comment: It is not an ellipse. Cassini ovals have somewhat different shapes. For some values of the constant the oval has two components.

Comment: oh god I didn't even know something like that existed, I guess an analytical solution is harder than i thought then. Anyways thank you @JyrkiLahtonen for clarifying that it's not even an ellipse :)